# Apply function to a list until first success (non-nil) and return this value

Tags: elisp

I have little experience with CL/ELisp and don't know any function that iterate list and apply another function until get non-nil value, which is returned from loop, leaving rest list unprocessed.

It like lazy `mapcar` or merged `or` with `apply`.

For example I like fold `while` loop into more declarative code in:

```
(defvar autobm-try-thingatpt-things
  '(symbol url email))

(defun autobm-try-thingatpt ()
  (let ((things autobm-try-thingatpt-things) name)
    (while (and things (not name))
      (setq name (thing-at-point (car things)))
      (setq things (cdr things)))
    name))
```

**UPDATE** With answer of I rewrote code to:

```
(require 'cl-lib)

(defun autobm-try-thingatpt ()
  (cl-some #'thing-at-point autobm-try-thingatpt-things))
```

It look elegant! Only question to experienced elispers why `cl-extra` does not `provide` itself? <del>So I must use `(load "cl-extra")`  instead of `(require 'cl-extra)`...</del>

Comment: In the case this question and [your another question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/10804/115) are related, `which-func` does this job for you. You simply provide it a list of functions you want to use in `which-func-functions` var and it won't execute the remaining functions in the list once a function returns a non-nil value (functions to the left in the list are executed first).

Comment: Yes. Currently I found 2 sources of func name for `prog-mode` but  like process any registered possible methods in specified list order until first success - in that way it is possible to set preferred method firstly and fall back to another. `semantic` for example also provide type of declaration so I can format it as `var: ...` or `fn: ...`, which isn't possible with `wich-func`....

Comment: You're supposed to just `(require 'cl-lib)` rather than loading a specific file (also you shouldn't be using `eval-when-compile` because you need the function at runtime, not compile time)

Comment: @npostavs Thanks for valuable notes! I search for `provide` in `cl-extra` but didn't find it. After all `cl-lib` do `(load "cl-loaddefs")` which has lines like `(autoload 'cl-some "cl-extra" ...)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for `cl-some`, which is found in `'cl-extra`. It takes a predicate<sup>1</sup> and a sequence, and returns the first non-nil call of the predicate called on each element of the sequence, or nil if that function returns nil on all elements of the sequence.

For simplicity, I'm going to use a helper function for this example

```
(defun if-negative-return-absolute-value (num)
  "If NUM is negative, return its absolute value. Otherwise, return nil."
  (when (< num 0)
    (abs num)))


(require 'cl-extra)

(cl-some  #'if-negative-return-absolute-value '(1 2 3))
=> nil    ;; if-negative-return-absolute-value returns nil on all elements

(cl-some  #'if-negative-return-absolute-value '(1 2 3 -4 -5))
=> 4      ;; the first non-nil result of if-negative-return-absolute-value
```

Your code can now be rewritten to be a lot simpler:

```
(defun autobm-try-thingatpt ()
  (cl-some #'thing-at-point autobm-try-thingatpt-things))
```

You may want to switch around the order of things in `autobm-try-thingatpt-things`; having the order be `'(url email symbol)` seems to be correct, as if point is inside a url or email, it'll still find a symbol, and urls can contain things that look like email addresses.

Thanks to @npostavs for pointing out the proper cl function to use here.

[1] A predicate is just a function used for the "truthiness" of its result -- whether it's `nil` or not.

Comment: I think they might have been asking for `cl-some`.

Comment: @npostavs Thanks, that's the function I couldn't find. I updated the answer to use it.

Comment: Wow! Exactly what I want, after you answer I quickly found Common Lisp functions: **EVERY, SOME, NOTEVERY, NOTANY** http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_everyc.htm for those tasks, for that reason I ask question here. Thanks +1

Answer (score 3):

```el
(defun autobm-try-thingatpt (fn)
  (let ((result  nil))
    (catch 'here
      (dolist (thg  autobm-try-thingatpt-things)
        (when (setq result  (funcall fn thg))
          (throw 'here result))))
    result))
```

That assumes that the result you want returned is the value of applying the function to the list element.  If instead you wanted the (first) list element for which applying the function to it returns non-nil, then set `result` to the `thg` before `throw`ing it.

Comment: To shorter code is last `result` required? Is it usual to do `let` inside `catch`?

Comment: 1. Explicitly returning `result` is clearer. It is not great style to rely on the return value of `dolist` (which will be the return value of the `catch` if there is nothing thrown) - it is less clear to a human reader what is going on. 2. The `catch` and `throw` are there to stop iterating when you find what you are looking for.