# How to detect if current major-mode supports which-function and semantic/find?

Tags: minor-mode

I am implementing a feature to automatically generate a bookmark name by extracting information from the current context. Many packages provide such info. For example `which-func` (through `(which-function)`) and `semantic/find` (through `(semantic-current-tag)`).

How do I detect availability/support of `which-func` or `semantic/find` for the current buffer?

Is this exposed by the mode writer through modes so from `(eq major-mode DESIRED-FEATURE-mode)` and `DESIRED-FEATURE-minor-mode` variable?

Answer (score 3):

You can check if `which-func` feature is useful in a major-mode by checking the value of the variable `which-func-functions`.

From the documentation:

> List of functions for `which-function` to call with no arguments.
>   It calls them sequentially, and if any returns non-nil,
>   `which-function` uses that name and stops looking for the name.

If the major-mode does not use `which-func`, the value of this variable will be `nil` and you will see `[???]` in the mode-line in bottom-right when you enable the `which-function-mode`.

If the major-mode makes use of `which-func`, you will see a list of function names assigned to this variable.

*The `which-func` package is not required by default and is autoloaded when you call the `which-function-mode` command. After that you will be able to access the `which-func-functions` variable.*

Comment: For instance, `verilog-mode` does not have `which-func` support but I [added my own support](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/tree/ad16c37943710e5ee8ae4c8a893d94d3f10be11e/setup-files/setup-verilog.el#L229-L233) by writing functions to parse strings for `which-func`:

Comment: The link in above comment points to a specific commit of my `setup-verilog.el`. If interested in the latest (with probably lesser bugs), see [**here**](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-files/setup-verilog.el).